# Database is not running in mongodb atlas due to unhandled promise exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My code is running fine in localhost with no warnings but when I'm changing my connection string to the string provided by mongodb atlas, following errors are showing which you can see in the below pic and my browser keeps circulating plz guide me what I'm doing wrong

> (node:13700) DeprecationWarning: 'open()' is deprecated in mongoose >=
> 4.11.0,
> use 'openUri() instead, or set the 'useMongoClient' option if using 'connect()' or 'createConnection()'. See
> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
> (Use 'node --trace-deprecation... to show where the warning was
> created)
>
> Server started on port 3000
>
> Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined
>
> at GetAddrInfoReqwrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {}] name: 'MongoError'
>
> at Pool.  (C:\Users\Umer\Desktop\node\Alhamdulillah, complete webapp\All Validations Completed\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js: 336:35)
>
> at Pool.emit (events.js:315 :20) at Connection. 
> (C:\Users\Umer\Desktop\node\Alhamdulillah, complet e webapp\A11
> Validations Completed\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\poo1
> Lis:280:12)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQTWA.jpg)

Comment: Hey, We will need to see the code as well.

Comment: Did you actualy look at the link provided in the error??

Comment: It seems your app do not read properly the mongodb server location uri: "undefined:27017"

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem that you're facing, it is because you're coding the `deprecated` method of connecting to the `MongoDB`.

**Your database.js file seems okay but I would suggest that you use `dotenv` and not a separate file for your secrets**

But in your app.js file, kindly completely change the way you're connecting to MongoDB.

```js
const config = require('./config/database')

const options = {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true}

mongoose.connect(config.mongoURI, options).then(
     ()=> console.log('connected to mongodb'),
     (reason)=> console.error(`Error: ${reason}`)
)

// All of your other code ahead.
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks, now unhandled promise exceptions error has vanished but now I'm facing a new error saying that Invalid mongodb uri "mongodb+src://...."

Comment: @SyedSamiUlHuda, Can you try to hardcode your `mongoDB` uri into the connect function.

Comment: I hardcoded too but localhost hardcode string work fine but when I'm changing it to my atlas string then it throws invalid uri error and when I'm removing +srv from string so on first connect error is showing

Comment: Boss I changed my version to 2.2.12 from 3.6 and then paste that string in my code and then no error is shown and all working fine but I can't get that where is my data going? in my localhost I open database then collection and then I can see my all documents but in cloud where is my documents collections database etc saved? can you plz last time help me?

Comment: @SyedSamiUlHuda, Uhmm...  In the cloud you login into cloud.mongodb.com, in the cluster section you will see that there is a button with the text `collections` click that you must be able to see your data.